# How can I detect pure PHP files?

Tags: php, ruby, bash, automated-refactoring

I need to execute some php beautifier and also convert some array()'s into []'s on lots of PHP files but I'm not sure about how to detect if they are indeed PHP and not mixed with HTML.

~/bin/findpurephpfiles

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Command
  def initialize
    while line = $stdin.gets do
      content = File.read(line.strip)
      begin
        if content.scan('<?').size == 1
          print line
        end
      rescue ArgumentError # invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
        $stderr.print "err with file: #{line}"
      end
    end
  end
end

Command.new
```

Executing it:

```
find . -name *.php |wc -l
3898

find . -name *.php |findpurephpfiles |wc -l
err with file: ./public/plugins/tiny_mce/plugins/jbimages/is_allowed.php
3848
```

Would you trust that condition `'<?' appears only once`

EDIT: seemed to work fine but created problems in production due to conflicting PHP versions (<5.4)

Comment: Nope, I wouldn't trust that at all.

Comment: I'm wondering why you want to convert `array()` to `[]`... It doesn't add anything useful and it's not even backwards compatible (php 5.4+).

Comment: You'd have to test against <? and <?php. Not saying that a trustable condition, I'm not sure, but if it were to be, you'd have to have both of those. Downside is if they had <?php at one point then <? later you'd be jacked. Might be better looking for closing tags - but then if they closed it that wouldn't work either. *shrug*

Comment: Without manual checking afterwards, this idea is probably not going to turn out well for you.

Comment: I'll trust git then :) @HamZa it reads easier. Also, it's not sth like a library that needs to be compatible with other projects.

Comment: What about whitespace or newline(s) after the closing `?>`. Can you make sure this will not happen (since you omit the `?>` at all in code files)?

Comment: (Why wouldn't you beautify PHP code with mixed HTML? [I build PHP prettyprinters that handle this just fine]) Hunting for "<?" etc. by themselves isn't safe; that text may be in a doc string literal.  The only accurate way to do this is to parse the file and see if it violates PHP syntax.  If you don't mind be wrong occasionally then a simple check will likely be fine.

Comment: @IraBaxter I don't remember why but I'll give it a try thanks. jsbeautifier didn't work for me though (sth wrong with php inside javascript inside html)